# Android Studio Error : No resource found that matches the given name

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-studio, mobile

I'm a beginner in Android Studio

I'm facing a problem when importing an old Eclipse project into Android Studio to practice :

[image]

A big list of almost the same Error Message, from what I found in similar questions it's about compatibility between the project and the google play services lib, but I don't know how to resolve it, any help please? (concrete steps)

here my app graddle : 
(

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 14
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 9
        targetSdkVersion 14
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:18.0.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:+'
}
```

I have updated all my libraries in Android studio !

Thanks,

Comment: Newest gms is not compatible with support 18... Moreover, support 18 should be compiled with 18 not 14

Comment: Thanks for your response, so what should i do to fix this issue ? change 18 to 14 ?